# Unique file identifiers on NTFS and $Object_ID

Tags: windows, file, filesystems, ntfs

From articles I have found online there appears to be two forms of unique identifiers for files on NTFS:

- Using Windows API GetFileInformationByHandle(), we can get access to the struct BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION, which contains a volume serial number and a low/high file index.
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363788(VS.85).aspx
- $Object_ID - The article http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2010/08/25/ntfs-file-attributes.aspx states:

> $OBJECT_ID – This is an attribute that holds an ID. This ID is used by the Distributed Link Tracking Service. An example of how it is used would be found in shortcuts. Make a shortcut on your desktop that points to a file. Then move that file. The shortcut will still function because it is using a way to tack the source file other than just the path and file name.
>
> Not all files will have an $OBJECT_ID attribute. In fact, it isn’t until an actual ID is to be assigned that the attribute is added to the file.

I am trying to understand when the Object ID is set. Here are a few questions:

1. When does the Object ID get assigned? It would appear based on the above article that in one scenario this occurs when a shortcut to a file is created.
2. Does the Object ID get assigned automatically when a file references another file, e.g. a Word document, which embeds a Visio diagram?
3. Do Object IDs only get assigned when Distributed Link Tracking is enabled/running or do they exist regardless of Distributed Link Tracking?
4. If I wanted to track a unique identifier for a file, would there be any advantage for me to use the Object ID (64 bytes) over the combined volume serial number and file index (low/high), which are 12 bytes combined.

Thanks, Elan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It All Depends On What You're Trying To Do.  :)

The file index number, like the [documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363788(VS.85).aspx), is really only a good identifier for the file in NTFS (as opposed to FAT), but even then it can change if the file is deleted and recreated (think backup/restore), though you might actually consider that a bonus if you were looking to distinguish those.

It's probably best not to worry about the link tracking service with regard to object IDs, and instead think of them as something you can [create/set/read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364557(v=VS.85).aspx), though again only in NTFS.

Object IDs have some overhead, whereas file IDs do not.  For most applications, I would probably end up picking file reference numbers (even though they are potentially fragile).

Comment: What do you mean by file reference numbers? Are you referring to the file index in NTFS?

Comment: File reference numbers are the IDs given to files.  The combination of the two fields you mentioned, low/high file index values, is the file reference number.  "Index" refers to a set of files.

Answer (score 4):

Figured I would put this here for others like me researching `FRN` and `OBJECTID`s. These IDs might be stable for directories (other than file restore) on a single file system, but both the FRN and the ObjectID will change as soon as you save and close a file with many different applications.

For example, if you open a Word file with FRN#: 1000 and you have assigned OBJECTID: 8675309, when you make a change, save, and close it. The FRN# will be a new number and there will be no ObjectID.

In the following I did a simple open, make a change to text in a paragraph, save and close of a word file. There are more than 52 events, in my program, I have filtered out all the `~WRL*tmp` files, etc that are involved. But even on the same file system with the same files, FRN is not a constant thing. I do not have ObjectID showing at the moment but trust me when you assign one, open this file and save it, it is essentially a new file.

Sample USN Journal output with the first number is the file reference number, the second is the Parent File Reference# (the FRN for the directory which is steady)

```
viewchanges
562949953421470    | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:13 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  OBJECT ID CHANGE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
562949953421470    | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:13 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  OBJECT ID CHANGE
                                                  CLOSE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
562949953421470    | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:19 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  RENAME OLD NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1125899906842780   | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:19 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  SECURITY CHANGE
                                                  RENAME NEW NAME
                                                  BASIC INFO CHANGE
                                                  OBJECT ID CHANGE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1125899906842780   | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:19 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  SECURITY CHANGE
                                                  RENAME NEW NAME
                                                  BASIC INFO CHANGE
                                                  OBJECT ID CHANGE
                                                  CLOSE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1125899906842780   | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:19 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  SECURITY CHANGE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1125899906842780   | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:19 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  SECURITY CHANGE
                                                  CLOSE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1125899906842780   | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:19 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  OBJECT ID CHANGE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1125899906842780   | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:19 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  OBJECT ID CHANGE
                                                  CLOSE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1125899906842780   | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:19 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  RENAME OLD NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1125899906842781   | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:19 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  SECURITY CHANGE
                                                  RENAME NEW NAME
                                                  BASIC INFO CHANGE
                                                  OBJECT ID CHANGE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1125899906842781   | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:19 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  SECURITY CHANGE
                                                  RENAME NEW NAME
                                                  BASIC INFO CHANGE
                                                  OBJECT ID CHANGE
                                                  CLOSE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1125899906842781   | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:19 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  SECURITY CHANGE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1125899906842781   | 2251799813685402   | FILE  | 7/10/2014 8:12:19 PM      | \MyDemo\WordFileDemo.docx
                                                  SECURITY CHANGE
                                                  CLOSE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: the ID is changed only because the application has chosen to save the content as a new file, remove the old one and rename the new file to the old one's. That will be true on any OS and file systems. The ID can only be retained in case you **write to the same file**